# How to implement different http method match different action with the url defined by myself based on Rails` REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Now,I have：

```
map.resources :questions, :collection => {
:query_by_student => :get
}
```

that matches：

```
query_by_student_questions GET /questions/query_by_student(.:format)
{:controller=>"questions", :action=>"query_by_student"}
```

I want add a "POST" request，to the same url:`/questions/query_by_student`，but the action should be `"post_by_student"`

waht shall I do？

怎么在Rails的REST基础上对自己定义的url，实现不同http方法对应不同action？

我现在有这：

```
map.resources :questions, :collection => {
:query_by_student => :get
}
```

对应路由信息：

```
query_by_student_questions GET /questions/query_by_student(.:format)
{:controller=>"questions", :action=>"query_by_student"}
```

我想加一个post请求，同样到`/questions/query_by_student`，但是action为`post_by_student`

怎么写？

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a testing app but with rails 2.2, you can try

```
map.resources :questions, :collection => {
   :query_by_student => [:get, :post]
}
```

and see what it looks like.

Otherwise, you can probably do it manually with something like

```
map.connect '/questions/query_by_student', :conditions => { :method => :get }, :controller => 'questions', :action => 'query_by_student'
map.connect '/questions/query_by_student', :conditions => { :method => :post }, :controller => 'questions', :action => 'post_by_student'
```

Comment: I haven`t try but I do not think that will lead to two different action.And the second way means map.resources could not make this function?